# How to conditional sum from gridview or from sql database in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a situation that I need to calculate total sum (from a SQL database table or from a gridview) column "ptarcvGV" if the column "PtR" cells equal to (combobox) AcPtPtrDd.selectedItem. In the following code I am getting total of all column cells in Label AcPTRcvdLbl.Text but **I want to get conditional total as per selection of combobox.text.(combobox having unique id numbers only , column "ptarcvGV" having partial Payment received, column "PtR" having repeated id numbers)**
code:

```
private void AcPtTrekBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ptarcvGV"].Value != null)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ptarcvGV"].Value.ToString());
            AcPTRcvdLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

One more thing that I did following line of code in SQL and worked fine but I am unable to use it in my c# form.
line of code:

```
Select SUM (pta_rcv) FROM PtAccounts where (pta_ptr) = 13   --13 is id in pta_ptr
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `if` condition as below.

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ptarcvGV"].Value != null &&
     dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PtR"].Value == AcPtPtrDd.selectedItem)
{
    //Your code
}
```

To compare string case insensitive way update conditions as follow.

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ptarcvGV"].Value != null &&
     string.Equals(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PtR"].Value.ToString(), AcPtPtrDd.SelectedItem.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    //Your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karan for quick reply. I just tried it but no error and no result. see my updated code as per your suggestion.   int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ptarcvGV"].Value != null &&
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ptaptrGV"].Value == AcPtPtrDd.SelectedItem)
                {
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ptarcvGV"].Value.ToString());
                AcPTRcvdLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);

Comment: `string.Equals(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PtR"].Value.ToString(), AcPtPtrDd.SelectedItem.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 0):

```
  decimal value = decimal.Parse(dt.Compute("SUM(columnName)","filterColumn='key'").ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks Jameel Nazir for your idea, I tried it, it gives error at dt.Compute as follows: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'filter' of 'Data table compute(string, string)'

Comment: condition will work like sql condition dont use single qoutes if key will be in numeric

Comment: Yes you are right. let me try it again. But I do not understand in the line of code that  PtR the criteria is there but it is missing the column "pta_rcv" to 'sum' received amount.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: dt is dataTabel variable and you suould replace column name that you should sum and condition column your column name which on you want to condition you can map  your column there and please mark my answer correct

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Karan for your idea it worked now with little change as follows:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ptaptrGV"].Value.ToString() == AcPtPtrDd.Text &&
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ptarcvGV"].Value != null)
```

I added ToString() and also changed at AcPtPtrDd.Text insted of AcPtPtrDd.SelectedItem

All done well

Answer (score 0):

```
double Sum_1 = 0;
double Sum_2 = 0;

foreach (GridViewRow row in gvComps.Rows)
{
   // sum all -- no condition
   Sum_1 += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].Text);

   // sum with condition
   if (row.Cells[7].Text=="yes")
       Sum_2 += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].Text);
}

txtSum_1.Text = Sum_1.ToString();
txtSum_2.Text = Sum_2.ToString();
```